# Как реализовать смену значений в блоке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть обект с которого берется значение и вставляется в тег. Но так как тега всего 3, должно быть в разметки , и само собой всю информацию сразу показать неудастся , нужно чтоб информация подгружалась по очереди. Как правильно сделать чтоб например при клике брались следующие значения с обекта и записывались в тег а предыдущие удалялись ?

Вот сам код :

```js
var json_date = {
  "dills": {
    "1": {
      "name": "boock_1",
      "time": "15:00",
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "book_2",
      "time": "15:00",
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "book_3",
      "time": "09:00",

    },
    "4": {
      "name": "book_4",
      "time": "05:00",

    }
  }
}


var ix = 0;

$.each(json_date['dills'], function(key, val) {



  $('li > h1').eq(ix++).text("").text(val.name);
  console.log(ix);
});
```

Вот весь код на фидле : https://jsfiddle.net/sxzk9ooa/6/

Comment: Удаляйте с помощью delete те объекты, которые уже выводили.     delete json_date['dills'][key]; и тогда при следующем переборе each начнет с первого оставшегося. И да, если $.each поведет себя неожиданно, попробуйте традиционный for(... in ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json_date = {
   "dills": {
     "1": {
       "name": "boock_1",
       "time": "15:00",
     },
     "2": {
       "name": "book_2",
       "time": "15:00",
     },
     "3": {
       "name": "book_3",
       "time": "09:00",

     },
     "4": {
       "name": "book_4",
       "time": "05:00",

     }
   }
 }

var ix = 0;

function objSliceOut (obj, start, offset) {
    var order = [];

    $.each(obj, function(key,val) {
        order.push(key);
    });


    $.each(order.slice(start, start + offset), function(i, key) {
        $('li > h1').eq(i).text(obj[key].name);
    });

    if((start + offset) < order.length) {
        ix++;
    }else{
        ix = 0;
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '#next', function() {
    objSliceOut(json_date['dills'],ix,3);
});

objSliceOut(json_date['dills'],ix,3);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sxzk9ooa/11/